# CXF web client testing with mock url

Tags: url, web, mocking, client, cxf

I use CXF 2.7.3 for web service creation.

I have XSLTJaxbProvider that reads a URL and pass URL path and query params to XSLT stylesheet that transformation into xml.
I want to test this using web client that uses XSLTJaxbProvider. But I need to use a Mock URL in my test and get the resultant xml that the xslt produces.

How to accomplish it? I did not find any such example in cxf web site.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.